# Is there something similar to if (--arr[i] < 0) in Python?

Tags: python

Didn't find a similar question. Say I have an array `count`, in C++ I can write an if statement like

```
if (--count[i] < 0) {
    return -1;
}
```

but in Python I have to do

```
if count[i] - 1 < 0:
    count[i] -= 1
    return -1
```

Just wonder if there is a better way or more concise way to write this python code. Thanks!

Comment: There are no post/pre increment/decrement operators.

Comment: Your translation is incorrect or incomplete, since the C++ code is decrementing before the test.

Comment: In Python you don’t typically write code that requires this kind of thing. The entire iterators/iterables/generators thing often obviates the need, because you’d implement your entire algorithm differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the walrus operator to perform an assignment in an expression

```
if (count[i] := count[i] - 1) < 0:
    return -1
```

Note that this is only equivalent for pre-increment. To get the equivalent of a post-increment test, you'd have to write this mouthful:

```
if [count[i], count[i] := count[i] - 1][0] < 0:
```

Comment: You could implement a post-{in,de}crement like `[x, x := x-1][0]` if you were really trying to be mean to future readers. This is guaranteed to work in python, unlike C where it'd be UB.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the answer with that mess.